# Core Service call for getting all Publications is throwing an error in SDL Tridion 2013

Tags: 2013, core-service

I am using the Core Service (SDL Tridion 2013) to retrieve the entire publication list.

Below is my code:

```
public XmlDocument GetPublicationList()
{
    XmlDocument publicationList = new XmlDocument();
    using (SessionAwareCoreServiceClient client = new SessionAwareCoreServiceClient(binding))
    {
        Logger.Write(string.Format("Core Service is ready  {0} ", client.ToString()), "CoreService", LoggingCategory.General, TraceEventType.Information);
        PublicationsFilterData filter = new PublicationsFilterData();
        XElement publications = client.GetSystemWideListXml(filter);
        Logger.Write(string.Format("Get Pulication list"), "CoreService", LoggingCategory.General, TraceEventType.Information);
        publicationList.Load(publications.CreateReader());
    }
    return publicationList;
}
```

This code is throwing Access denied error:

```
Access is denied for the user NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE.
  Component: Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService Errorcode: 770 User: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE  StackTrace Information Details:
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Security.AuthorizationManager.LoadAccessToken(String userName, IEnumerable`1 mappedGroupUris, IEnumerable`1 claimSets)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Session..ctor(IEnumerable`1 claimSets)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.CoreServiceBase.get_CurrentSession()
   at Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.CoreServiceBase.GetSystemWideListXml(SystemWideListFilterData filter)
   at SyncInvokeGetSystemWideListXml(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.CoreServiceInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
```

Comment: This could be your answer:

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12044338/tridion-coreservice-authentication-impersonation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The context in which you application lives (likely web based on the user) is running as user `NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE`.

This user is not configured within SDL Tridion as an allowed user.

Either try running the Core Service call as a valid SDL Tridion user, or add `NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE` as a user within SDL Tridion.

As Saurabh says, this post should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12044338/tridion-coreservice-authentication-impersonation